# Reversing only a part of a list in python

Tags: python, list

How could I do lines 3 to end in one line?

```py
arr = [some array]

helper = arr[index:end]
helper.reverse()
for i in range(index1 + 1, len(arr)):
    arr[i] = helper[i-index-1]
```

This is my attempt to reversing only some part of a list.

Comment: `helper = [index:end]` is invalid syntax...

Comment: Anyway, you can just do something like `arr[index:end] = arr[index:end][::-1]`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
start = 5
end = 8
rev=arr[start:end]
arr[start:end]=rev[::-1]
```

Comment: I found a simpler solution, see my answer, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

After reading about slices I found a very simple solution:

```
arr[index:end] = arr[index:end][::-1]
```

This was also mentioned in the comments by juanpa.arrivillaga and can be found in the python documentation about slices.